# MySQL query to sum all distinct values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
uid_from uid_to count
   x1      x2    3 
   x3      x2    5
   x8      x1    99
   x9      x1    1
```

And would like to generate a summ table like this:

```
uid_to   sum
  x1     100
  x2      8
```

I can do it in PHP, but would rather do it directly in a MySQL query. I should note the table has 700 Million rows.

Comment: Why does the title to your question say "*all **distinct** values*"?

Comment: @eggyal cuz I wanna sum all the distinct uid_to values. Thought about the problem wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select uid_to, sum(count) as sum
from your_table
group by uid_to
```

Comment: thanks. do you think this will end in within a reasonable time?

Comment: Yes. If not take a look at the indexes of your table.